# How to convert a MySQL database and a PHP/JS application into an image that can be deployed in a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml

I have an application prepared in PHP/JS using a MySQL database.
Can I convert my application and database into images executable in a Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: I would say start by reading this https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/php/ .. once the image is ready then deploying it on the kube cluster is another story.. not difficult though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You should be able to convert your application into one docker image and your database into another docker image. Then create a Kubernetes deployment file (YAML) with two services...one being DB and the other being App with the App depending on the DB service.

See this [link](https://github.com/dockersamples/k8s-wordsmith-demo) for a sample (though not in php)

Comment: Suppose I place both the images at docker, where would the data added by users be stored / updated?  Suppose I use my private server to store the data, would it automatically be configured to work with the image?